# validation occuring before onSubmit when integrating formik-material-ui for material-ui styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I want to add material-ui to my formik app. I am using the formik-material-ui library (https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui) to do this. However, when i insert the material-ui textfield components into the fields, validation triggers before submitting. My hunch is that it is a mapStateToProps problem, but I am not sure how to integrate that into my code as there isn't much documentation on it.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik, Field, Form} from 'formik';
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui'; 

class Post0 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            'email': this.props.initValues.email,
            'animal':  this.props.initValues.animal,
          }}   
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
              .email('Invalid email address')
              .required('Please enter an email address'),
            animal: Yup.string().required('Required'),
          })} 
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            this.props.nextStep(values);   
          }}
          render={({ values, isSubmitting}) => (  
            <Form>
              <Field
                name="email"
                type="email"
                value={values.email}
                component={TextField}
                variant="outlined"
              />
              <Field
                name="animal"
                value={values.animal}
                component={TextField}
                variant="outlined"
              />

              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Post0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default with Formik, validation happens when inputs lose focus (i.e. after `onBlur()` is triggered by an input). Is this what you are talking about? You can change this behaviour if you want with with the `validateOnBlur` setting ([see the Formik documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#validateonblur-boolean)).

See your example with `validateOnBlur` set to `false` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqr02v9yp3).